# Adding href to CHTML::image

Tags: php, yii, yii-chtml

I'm currently using an image in my navbar but I also want to make clicking this return to the home page.

I thought adding ,array('href' => 'imagepath.png') would work but had no luck so far and it seems to break the page!

this is the code I am trying to change.

```
 echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'imagepath');
```

Keep in mind I have tried

```
echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'imagepath',
array('href' => 'imagepath'));
```

Also trying

```
echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'imagepath'); 
echo CHtml::link($image,array('baseurl/page','id'=>'page_id'));
```

Answer : To get an image to link back to the homepage or chosen baseurl.

```
$img= CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/imagepath');
$link = CHtml::link($img, Yii::app()->request->baseUrl);
echo $link;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$img= CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/imagepath','altText',array('height'=>100,'width'=>100));
$link = CHtml::link($img, array('baseurl/page','id'=>'page_id'));
echo $link;
```

Comment: Excellent, works great.

$link = CHtml::link($img, Yii::app()->request->baseUrl);

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `<a>` and have a `<img>` inside it. So I think it's better to use normal html in your case:

```
<a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('baseurl/page', array('id'=>'page_id')); ?>">
   <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'imagepath'  ?>" />
</a>
```